# Retagging to include tags for possible solutions

Tags: discussion, tags

This morning, I got in a brief back and forth [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720029/how-to-validate-a-string-from-a-set-of-permuted-values-with-fixed-prefixes-in-c#comment18846560_13720029) regarding the usage of tags and whether a retagging was appropriate.

Is adding tags for possible solutions or technologies the correct course of action regardless of the OP's desires, or should tags be limited the ONLY the technologies that the OP would like.

The original question has only the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, but along the way a user with retag privileges decided that this question was a `RegEx` question and added [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).  Since the OP did not make any reference to `RegEx`, I felt it was an improper retagging as you are possibly limiting the scope of the question to `RegEx` answers and rolled back.  However, the retagger disagrees saying that he was expanding the scope of the question to include `RegEx`.

While I see the point that there is some value to broadcasting it out to the followers of the RegEx tag, I still don't agree as using that logic, we should retag any solution that could possibly solved with LINQ as [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) and since XPATH can solve may of the same issues as LINQ-2-XML, they should include [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) whether or not the OP wanted it.  It just opens the possibility of too many irrelevant tags just because a specific technology might solve a problem.

Am I correct in my interpretation, or do I need re-educated on tag usage?

Comment: Related posts: [Retagging questions with the answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35842/166025), [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26913/166025), [Retagging questions in terms of possible answer technologies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52466/166025), [Should Tags Be Chosen by Direct Relation to Question or Also Indirect Relation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8007/166025)